# NO PERMITE ingresar registros

Tags: html

EL PROBLEMA SUCEDE CUANDO DESEO INGRSAR REGISTROS, MOSTRANDOME LOS REGISTROS CORRECTOS DE LA BASE DEDATOS, PERO NO ME MUESTRA EL QUE DESEO INGRESAR EN LA PAGINA DEL INDEX.

```
class Crud{

    //insertamos LOS REGISTROS QUE RECIBIMOS DESDE EL INDEX
    public function insert($obj) {
        try {
            $campos = implode("', '" , array_keys($obj));
            $valores = ": " . implode(", :", array_keys($obj));
            //vamos a setear la consulta
            $this->sql = "INSERT INTO {$this->tabla} ('{$campos}') VALUES ({$valores}) ";
            $this->ejecutar($obj);
            //permite llamar el ID insertado usando la conexion y el metodo lastInsertID
            $id= $this->conexion->lastInsertId();
            return $id;
        } catch (Exception $exc) {
            echo $exc->getTraceAsString();
        }
    }
    //Y CON ESTO NO ENTIENDO MUY BIEN Y SI ME EXPLICAN LES AGRADECERIA MUCHOTE
    private function ejecutar($obj=null){
        $statement= $this->conexion->prepare($this->sql);
        if($obj!==NULL){
            foreach ($obj as $llave => $valor){
                if(empty($valor)){//comprueba si el valor esta indedinido
                    $valor=null;//y lo seteamos a null
                }
                //$stmt -> bindParam(':usuario',$_POST['usuario']);
                $statement->bindValue(":$llave", $valor);//seteamos los valores de nuestro obj
            }
        }
        $statement->execute();
        $this->reiniciarValores();
        return $statement->rowCount();
    }

    //vamos a reiniciar los valores para reutilizarlos
    private function reiniciarValores(){
        $this->wheres="";
        $this->sql=NULL;
    }
}
```

en el Index que les mostrè ingreso el registro, pero en la clase CRUD no me deja ingresar ningun registro. No sè donde esta el problema si es en el Indez o en el CRUD, la conexion esta todo bien.

Answer (score 0):

ya lo encontre muchamos, el unico problema radicaba en las comillas simples ' que se encuentran dentro de la funcion "insert", estas tenian que ser cambiadas por ` un simbolo que se forma con alt + 96